# How to set servlet context path in Spring Boot Tests?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-test

I write integration test using Spring Boot 2.1.2.RELEASE and can't set needed context path. It's always equal to empty string (got with servletContext.getContextPath()).

application-test.properties:

```
server.servlet.context-path=/app
```

Test config:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ContextConfiguration
@Import({MailSenderAutoConfiguration.class, ThymeleafAutoConfiguration.class})
@WebAppConfiguration
@TestPropertySource(locations="classpath:application-test.properties")
public class MyServiceTests {...}
```

Calling code:

```
@Value("#{'${application.base-url}' + servletContext.contextPath}")
private String siteUrl;
```

Other properties in application-test.properties are injected as expected. Context path is normally set when I run server. I've tried to launch this test as a @SpringBootTest, provided a context path in variable @TestPropertySource(locations="classpath:application-test.properties", properties = "server.servlet.context-path=/app") but without results. How can I set context path for my test?

Comment: This is a bit of a strange question because you usually write java code in a manner that allows the context root to either be supplied at runtime or to not exist at all.

Comment: Can you share the code that you are using to read it?

Comment: @muasif80 - updated post

Answer (score 0):

I've found such walkaround:

File application-test.properties:

```
application.base-url=http://test.ru
server.servlet.context-path=/app
application.root-url=${application.base-url}${server.servlet.context-path:}
```

Calling code:

```
@Value("${application.root-url}")
private String siteUrl;
```